# Prevent MEF Extension from crashing Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crash, mef

I have deployed a visual studio language service using MEF. It is in beta right now internally, and is prone to crashing every now and then.

I have been working to shield code from crashes, but I have been told that people will stop using it unless I have a way of ensuring 100% stability.

So I ask: **Is there a way to block a MEF extension from closing Visual Studio if it crashes?** I have been told there cannot be any chance of it crashing VS. I know this is a bit of a long-shot, but it's what I have to do. I am being as pro-active with my coding as I can, but with multiple hands in the pot... the odd bug does get through still and the users have deemed that unacceptable.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".